# Insert for linked list pseudo code

Tags: algorithm, insert, linked-list, pseudocode, doubly-linked-list

In Introduction to Algorithm Ed 3, I read pseudo code algo for inserting element in a linkedlist, and i do not understand the middle step.

```
x.prev = L.head
if L.head != NIL
    L.head.prev = x
L.head = x
x.prev = NIL
```

and if my original linked list is `HEAD -- 4 -- 24`, I understand that the steps are the following:

1. HEAD -- 4 -- 24
2. x -- 4 -- 24
3. HEAD -- x -- 4 -- 24

with 2. corresponding to

```
x.prev = L.head
```

Why do we have to insert x before head with

```
 if L.head != NIL
        L.head.prev = x
```

?

Could smbdy clarify ?

Comment: You have changed the pseudo code from CLRS, was it intentional? First line should be `x.next = L.head` not `x.prev = L.head`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say, Initially Head is pointing to node [Y], that means [Y] is the current head. We are going insert new node [X], which will become head node of our list, so head pointer will point to [X].

Here remember that, at the beginning of time (before inserting anything to the list) Head will point to NiL.

Now lets go step by step with the pseudo code to see what is going on:

Current situation of our list is: `Head -> [Y], [Y].prev -> NiL`, as head is pointing to [Y], so until we change the Head pointer, whenever we use Head you can think/read it as [Y]. Now current head node [Y] will go after [X], so lets set next of [X] = [Y]

```
1. x.next = L.head
```

After the fist statement, we have `[X].next->[Y],  Head->[Y], [Y].prev->NiL`

```
2. if (L.head != NIL) //At the beginning Head might be pointing to NiL, and of course NiL.prev does not exist and we do not want to access illegal location.
    3. L.head.prev = x //if head is not pointing to Nil then it is pointing to [Y],
                       //in that case [X] will be the prev node of [Y], 
                    //so after this line, have Head->[Y], [X].next->[Y], [Y].prev->[X]
```

After 3rd line, we can safely set our list Head pointer to point [X]

```
4. L.head = x    
5. x.prev = NIL //You can write L.head.prev = NIL, as [X] is now the new head
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint is that

> L:head:pre denotes the pre attribute of the object that L:head
>   points to

Then, algo goes as follows

```
    //HEAD -- 4 -- 24

    x.next = l.head
    if L.head != NIL
        L.head.prev = x

    //x -- 4 -- 24

    L.head = x
    x.prev = NIL

   //HEAD -- x -- 4 --24
```